# ISO 8601 date format - Add day with javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add days to date with ISO 8601 Format using Javascript.

```
var date = new Date(2013, 9, 18, 18, 0, 0);
var myDate = date + 1
```

Comment: There is no ISO-8601 anywhere in that question. :-) ISO-8601 is a way to describe dates as *text*, e.g. `"2013-10-18T18:00:00"`. JavaScript doesn't do ISO-8601 (although it [does something very similar](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2014/07/javascripts-datetime-format-is-not-iso.html)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will add a day to the date:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
```

Comment: @IshanMahajan Works for me. I just set the variable to today's date (July 31), and when I used `setDate(date.getDate()+1)` it changed to August 1.

Comment: @IshanMahajan If you can't get it to work, post a question showing your code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [api for Date over on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var date = new Date(2013, 9, 18, 18, 0, 0);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```